# Receiving a null pointer exception

Tags: java, if-statement, nullpointerexception

I'm receiving a null pointer exception from some code I've wrote, I cannot see the reason for the exception. This is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SearchingFilesMain {

public static void main(String[] arg) {

    int checker4 = 0;
    String checker3 = "";
    String checker2 = "";
    String checker1 = "";
    String checker = "";

    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\asciiTracks.txt")));

        while (checker != null) {

            String pattern = "Array Start";
            checker = scan.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 0);

            if(checker.equals("Array Start")){

                String pattern2 = "Array Size";
                checker3 = scan.findWithinHorizon(pattern2, 300);
                System.out.println(checker3);

                if(checker3.equals("Array Size")){                      
                    checker4 = Integer.parseInt(scan.findInLine("(10000|\\d{1,4})"));
                    System.out.println(checker4);


                }else{System.out.println("no array size");}
        System.out.println(checker4);
    }else{System.out.println("no array size");}}}catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}}}
```

This is the error i get on the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at SearchingFilesMain.main(SearchingFilesMain.java:31)
```

This error occurs at this line of the code:

```
if(checker3.equals("Array Size")){
```

This makes no sense to me, as surely if checker3 is not equal to the text it will simply move onto the else statement and go from there, rather than just throw null pointer exception and stop the program? Am i wrong in thinking this?

Anyone got any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Please check with "checker3" its get null value from 
checker3 = scan.findWithinHorizon(pattern2, 300);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though you have initialized `checker3` with empty string, it is overrited by `checker = scan.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 0);` which seems to be returning `null`.

To avoid `NullPointerException` you should add `null` check in your `if` statement -

```
if(checker!=null && checker.equals("Array Start")){
   ...
}else{
   ...
}
```

Comment: okay thank you, yeah i realised it was returning null because that's precisely what it should return, but i couldn't see how it was managing to throw the null pointer exception. Thank you for clarifying :D

Comment: `"Array Start".equals(checker)` is more concise as there's no need to explicitly check for null.

Answer (score 2):

`scan.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 0)` may returning `null` into `checker3` and
calling `equals()` on it gives you `NullPointerException`.

If you want you ignore this exception,change your condition to

```
 if("Array Size".equals(checker3)){
 }
```

here the condition is `false` when `checker3` is not equals to `"Array Size"` and also when `checker3` is `null`, otherwise it is `true`

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `checker3 = scan.findWithinHorizon(pattern2, 300);` causes it to be `null`

If `checker3` is not initalized, it will be `null`, and calling a method on reference variable that refer to `null` will result into `NullPointerException`.

Comment: okay but why isn't checker3 initialized then? It should be initialized before the entire while statement.

Comment: it is initialized to a blank string before while loop, but in while loop the call to findWithinHorizon is returning null

Answer (score 1):

```
checker3 = scan.findWithinHorizon(pattern2, 300);
```

I can only assume that the above line of code is assigning a `null` value to `checker3`.